How to upload file in ASP.NET MVC with ajax?
I'm using ASP.NET MVC (for target framework .NET 4.6.1).
In the view, I have this markup:
<form id="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" />
    <button type="button" id="uploadButton">Upload</button>
</form>

This is the jQuery part:
$('#uploadButton').click(function () {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#fileInput')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
               url: '/Controller/Action',
               type: 'POST',
               data: formData,
               processData: false,
               contentType: false,
               success: function (response) {
                   // Handle success response
                   console.log('File uploaded successfully:', response);
                   alert('success');
               },
               error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                   // Handle error response
                   console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
                   alert('error');
               }
           });
       });

Controller action method
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    int statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

    try
    {
        // Do your functionality...  
        statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
        statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }

    return new JsonResult { Data = new { statusCode } };
}

But, in file I am getting null.
I also tried another way, install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http package.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
{
    int statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

    try
    {
        // Do your functionality...  
        statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
        statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }

    return new JsonResult { Data = new { statusCode } };
}

But, it is the same. file is null

By adding the following properties to the ajax call, I got it working with the first controller method you posted with the HttpPostedFileBase file class as input parameter:
async: false,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
enctype: 'multipart/form-data'

Please give it a try.
